Are the Hermitian linear functionals of a $C^{\ast}$-algebra necessarily bounded?
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a (complex) $C^{\ast}$-algebra, and let $\varphi$ be a linear functional of $\mathcal{A}$. $\varphi$ is said to be hermitian if and only if $$\forall x \in \mathcal{A}\text{,}\hspace{0.5 cm} \varphi(x^{\ast}) = \overline{\varphi(x)}\text{.}$$
In his book An introduction to operator algebras, Zhu claims that Hermitian functionals are always bounded, and such claim can be later found as an exercise. However, this exercise has been haunting me for weeks, and I have not been able to solve it:
It is known that the positive functionals of $\mathcal{A}$ (those that map the positive elements of $\mathcal{A}$ to nonnegative real numbers) are bounded. A proof of this fact can be found in the book $C^{\ast}$-algebras and operator theory (Murphy), and I tried to modify it so it could be valid for hermitian functionals as well, but such proof depends on certain order-preserving properties of positive functionals. Then, I tried to work with the linear functionals of $\mathcal{A}$ as elements of some $C^{\ast}$-algebra, without success. Finally, I tried to read some works about operator algebras, but all the works I found worked only with bounded linear functionals…
I would deeply appreciate some help regarding this matter.

Maybe the claim Zhu had in mind was that Hermitian multiplicative functionals are bounded?

@QiaochuYuan Multiplicative linear functionals are automatically Hermitian (in fact, automatically positive). It would be strange if Zhu specifically said Hermitian but was actually intending for the linear functional to be multiplicative.

The edition I am studying with is from 1993. In the page 77, Hermitian linear functionals are defined exactly as mentioned. After that, it can be read “It can be shown that Hermitian functionals are always bounded (see Exercise
13.7). Also we shall see a little later that positive functionals are Hermitian.”. There is little room for interpretation.

This is not true. Indeed, any linear functional $\varphi$ is a linear combination of two Hermitian linear functionals: let $\varphi_r(x) = \frac{1}{2}(\varphi(x) + \overline{\varphi(x^\ast)})$ and $\varphi_i(x) = \frac{1}{2i}(\varphi(x) - \overline{\varphi(x^\ast)})$. Both are Hermitian and $\varphi = \varphi_r + i\varphi_i$. Thus, if all Hermitian linear functionals are bounded, all linear functionals would be bounded. Since any infinite-dimensional Banach space admits a unbounded linear functional, the claim must be false.

Or, in a similar vein, take an unbounded linear functional on the (real) Banach space of self-adjoint elements of $\mathcal{A}$, then complexify it to a linear functional on the entirety of $\mathcal{A}$. It is easily seen to be Hermitian but unbounded.
